# How to organize classes inside my Yii application?

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to organize my Yii application a bit and extracting some logic into separate classes. If I put those new classes under *protected/models*, they become visible without explicit import via autoloader functionality.

Now I am having 54 files under the *models* directory and number keeps growing.

**How to** enable Yii finding classes that are in the subdirectories of *models*, like:

- protected/models/core
- protected/models/logging
- protected/models/utils

etc...

Comment: maybe interesting? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html. It seems to be a standard PSR-4 autoloader. Ensure all the files have the full namespace, as the first executable PHP line, for the directory they live in. It should find and load the classes. i.e. all the files in `protected/models/logging`. Must have namespaces of 'protected/models/logging'. Ensure lettercase is correct.

Comment: for earlier versions of YII then It is suggested to use an external autoloader. I am familiar with AURA (i currently use this) and have use the Symfony standalone autoloader. Either will do want you want really easily.

Comment: @RyanVincent I am on Yii 1.1. For new projects using Symfony 3.

Comment: what do you want to do with your Yii 1.1 project? 1) learn to use an auto-loader? You can use it with any project you decide. 2) have some config files that you use to 'include_once' your class files. Seriously, you don't have a lot of files and option 2) is really easy initially. Option 1) more learning initially - it is well documented and there are real examples. I will gladly help with either method. I suggest we use the  AURA autoloader. why? I just have code examples handy :)